# javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /index.xhtml

Tags: jsf, el

I have the following form

```
 <h:form>
   `<h:selectManyCheckbox id="booksSelectManyCheckBox" required="true" layout="pageDirection" value="#
{CartBeans.selectedBooks}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{CartBeans.selectableBooks}"/>
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    <p>
       <h:commandButton value="Add to Cart" action="#{cartBeans.addToCart}"/>
    </p>
</h:form'
```

and this method

```
 public void setSelectedBooks(){
      selectedBooks.add("0136053068");
      selectedBooks.add("0132575663");
      selectedBooks.add("032459951X");
      selectedBooks.add("013605332X");
      selectedBooks.add("013605305X");
 }

 public List <String> getSelectedBooks(){
      selectedBooks.clear();
      return selectedBooks;
 }
```

Still I get the error that the property is not writable, What can Ii do to get the strings to show?

Answer (score 0):

Change your setter to:

```
public void setSelectedBooks(List<String> selectedBooks){
      selectedBooks.add("0136053068");
      selectedBooks.add("0132575663");
      selectedBooks.add("032459951X");
      selectedBooks.add("013605332X");
      selectedBooks.add("013605305X");
}
```

Even if you mock the setter, the method signature must be right.